# UI Blocked when a global exception is caught

Tags: android, uncaught-exception

In my app I'm trying to handle global exceptions using `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

When my app finds any uncaught exception, I'm trying to catch it globally in the Application class and also in fragments.

My application has many fragments on an activity. If it crashes in any of the fragment I want the app to remove that fragment and it should show the previous fragment and it is working as desired. But the **UI(main thread) is blocked**. If I try to access anything in the main thread, it shows a dialog saying '**app is not responding**'

```
@Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        System.out.println(TAG + "The Uncaught exception is-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (activityContext != null){

            removeTopfragment();   //removes the top most fragment
        }
    }



private void removeTopfragment() {


        System.out.println("inside removeTopfragment");
        FragmentManager manger = activityContext.getSupportFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction ft = manger.beginTransaction();

        List<Fragment> list = manger.getFragments();
        //get last one
        if(list.size()  > 0) {

            System.out.println("inside list.size() ");
            Fragment topFragment = list.get(list.size() - 1);


            ft.remove(topFragment);
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();



        }

    }
```

I don't want to kill/restart the app. Please help

Comment: @Naveen Tamrakar Thanks for the edit..

Comment: to be fair, you should be focussing on solving the actual issue: stop writing code that throws exceptions that will crash the app. Write code without issues and use a tool like Firebase to analyze crashlogs.

Comment: Ya, I did that too.. But to avoid the message like '**Unfortunately, your app has stopped**'  I have added this. This is one of the requirement.

Comment: Do you also know why you see that error? It doesn't seem like you're logging the error except for a `printStackTrace`

Comment: To test this feature, I have created a null pointer exception in one of the fragment and as desired the app is not getting crashed because that exception is catched. But as soon as it is catched, it is blocking the UI.

Comment: so if you deploy your app to customers, how do you fix errors? How do you know what causing `Unfortunately, your app has stopped`.

Comment: Once I clear this issue, I will write the exception to a file and will move it to cloud. In the mean while i want to shift back to the previous fragment when it caught an error. I have edited my question and added the code for fragment removal. But the problem is, remove fragment is not working because the UI is blocked. The same remove fragment piece of code is working in other places of my app.